# Download a lot of images from url

Tags: image, download

If I have a txt file, which contains the url that downloads images, how do we write the script to do that?

e.g. txt file information:

http://forensics.inf.tu-dresden.de/ddimgdb/images/gallery/Canon_Ixus55_0_3194.JPG

http://forensics.inf.tu-dresden.de/ddimgdb/images/gallery/Canon_Ixus55_0_3198.JPG

...

Comment: what language are you looking for?

Comment: Any language is fine with me.

Comment: The speed of download using this script should be as quick as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright Ill help you, though you do not have a good track record on questions or accepting answers.

```
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

String[] URLList = File.ReadAllLines(C:\yourURLFile.txt");

foreach (String URL in URLList) {
    using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {
         webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(URL), @"C:\PicFolder\"); 
    }
}
```

This code reads a URL file into a string[] and then iterates through it downloading the files and saving it to the LocalDIR

Comment: Thanks. I accepted your answer. I am trying your code. Looks like this is based on Java. I just curious does other popular language have this kinds of functions similar to this WebClient.DownloadFile? Anyway. Thanks~~~~~~~~~`

Will you be able to add one more function, like you skill download that one if it is already been downloaded

Comment: This is written in C#

Comment: Thank you for corrections. I did not see the "using" this keyword for c#.

Comment: They are all going to be a little different (unless you go Vb, ASP, F#), but all of them have a similar function

Comment: Do you have any way to find the similar function in another language, e.g., Java.   WebClient class, DownloadFile method mapping to Java's which class, which method? How do we know that? only based on programming experience?

Comment: I tried your code in the Visual Studio 2015. It looks like your code can execute successfully until we need to add exception handling ?

Comment: I added the exception handling. But your code still could not work successfully.

Comment: When I get home later tonight I'll do some debugging. Would you rather have it in Java?

Comment: Thank you so much. If you can provide Java version, it will also very helpful to my learning programming. I am looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: If you could debug this C#, it will be also very good since I already studied these code for more than 1 hour

Comment: Give this a try, just make sure that the URL's are loading correctly

Comment: Thanks. I use Windows, I put: String[] URLList = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\User\\Desktop\\TheFile.txt");
Because single \ did not work.

But output: The program '[1072] ImageDownload.vshost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: Yes, I have declared it for sure.

Comment: If you comment out the code, are you able to run the application or are you getting the same error? Try Cleaning, rebuilding, and ctrl+f5

Comment: What do you mean comment out the code? which part code do I need to comment out? Are you be able to run your code in Visual Studio 2015? Thank you so much for your time.